# Where/how can I easily host an interactive Julia ipython notebook?

Tags: ipython, shiny, julia

I've got a little interactive applet in Julia which I'd like to put online. What's the easiest way? Should I host it on my own server? Or is there a service for this (e.g. something similar to shinyapps.io?) I tried on SageMath with no luck, happy to post a MWE if someone wants to help me debug there.

Comment: Did you check https://www.juliabox.org/? more details: http://stanford.edu/class/ee103/slides/julia_box_slides.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use **JuliaBox**, now it's hosted online at http://www.juliabox.org/, but you can clone it from https://github.com/JuliaLang/JuliaBox and make your own server.
simply log in with your Gmail account, and run interactive sessions online.

Comment: I like juliabox for interactive use, but I don't think it is possible to publish notebooks for others to use on it, just JuliaWebAPI services?

Comment: I tried JuliaBox, but as @lossleader says it doesn't seem like there's a way to publish them as interactive. Next best thing, I guess is to just share the notebook and suggest people use JuliaBox if they don't have Julia installed. But it'd be great if there was a place to host it so people, can, e.g. just play with the widget without needing to install or sign-up for anything.